# Wordpress and WHMCS in same directory

Tags: wordpress, whmcs

I currently have wordpress and WHMCS both running my site.  Wordpress is in the root, WHMCS is in a folder.

The result is that WHMCS pages show the url structure domainname.com/foldername/pagename

I have spoken with my developer who says that there is no way to set the system up to result in domainname.com/pagename if we want to keep running both WP and WHMCS together, because two index.php files can't operate in the same folder (obviously).

Can anyone that understands this much better than I do confirm that what he's saying is correct, or provide a means to an ends.  I just want to double check that no-one has any alternative that will yield the ideal results.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`.htaccess` in your WordPress folder is responsible for creating a URL structure based on the directory path.

In order to ignore the subdirectory installation by the WordPress, try adding this code inside `.htaccess` at the top.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/whmcs_directory_name/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
</IfModule>
```